# Receiving NullPointerException while using Jasypt and Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring, security, jasypt

I am trying to configure Jasypt with Spring Security.  My configuration file looks like this:

```
    jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8090/sample
    jdbc.username=ENC(*****) where the *****=the salted username
    jdbc.password=ENC(*****) where the *****=the salted password
```

My servlet xml contains the proper bean setup in this format:

```
 <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
  <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="configurationEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
  <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="environmentVariablesConfiguration"
      class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig">
  <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWithMD5AndDES" />
    <property name="passwordEnvName" value="APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD" />
  <!--<property name="password" value="**********" />-->
</bean>
       <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
   </bean>
```

My environment variable is set in windows properly for APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD.  It is visible when I echo it from command line.  When I use this setup, I get the null pointer stack trace below.  When I use the hard coded salt password "-->", my application runs smoothly.  Can someone show me why Jasypt or Spring might not be picking up on my environment variable properly?  Any information would be welcomed.  Thanks.

```
 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:740)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:590)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705)
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
    at org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperty(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Aug 7, 2013 8:46:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimplePBEConfig.getPasswordCharArray(SimplePBEConfig.java:434)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.resolveConfigurationPassword(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:740)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:590)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705)
    at org.jasypt.properties.PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.decrypt(PropertyValueEncryptionUtils.java:72)
    at org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperty(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertProperties(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:662)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: So, just to confirm, executing `echo %APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD%` in a prompt yields the correct value and you're definitely not passing in the property as `-DAPP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=foo`?

Comment: Are you running the program from Eclipse IDE?

Comment: to answer the first question, yes.  The correct value is displayed.  2nd question is also yes.  I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: I had the same problem on windows machine but it works in linux server pretty well. For development purpose you could directly provide the password value in your configuration file. But later could be removed during final deployment.

Comment: Thanks @ShamimAhmmed.  I guess I'll hard code it for development purposes although that is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try restarting windows command prompt and try again.

I got similar error and after setting up env variable, I forgot to restart windows command prompt and was getting same error.

Restarting windows command prompt resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else facing this issue and stumbling upon this question, restarting Eclipse fixed the issue. 
**Note:** you must close Eclipse fully then re-open. Clicking "Restart" won't work as it doesn't kill the Java process completely.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an environment variable we were counting on to use as seed

Whoever has created your setup readme, read it

:)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are in Linux environment,
   type:
   export APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=CUSTOM_KEY
2. If you are in Windows environment, set the environment variable:
   set APP_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD as variable, set CUSTOM_KEY as value